# Issue while uploading app on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios

I am trying to upload an app. The issue is, I am testing it on my own account but now my app is complete so I have to live it on client's account. What changes should i make in certificates, provision profile etc to make it live. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make changes in certificates, but you have to change certificates.

Ask your client to login to apple developer website and download those certificates from their account.
Then use those certificates while archiving the app, give archived app to client for publishing to App Store.

OR, if possible, ask your client for their account credentials, add their account to your Xcode and Xcode will automatically manage all the certificate related stuff(signing certificate, downloading it, signing your app to that certificate).

For automatic managing this stuff, enable this in project setting:
[image]

Then just archive and directly publish to iTune Connect from Xcode itself for publishing on App Store.

Comment: Yes, you have to change it because Xcode will generate error saying bundle id already taken by another account. Use com.clientcompany.appname like bundle